# What is the most efficient way to store a static list of Objects?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, arraylist, hashmap

I'm trying to store a list of different Enemies. Each Enemy has an origin and can only spawn in its Location of origin. Each enemy also has a difficulty and should be stored with enemies of the same difficulty.

I imagined it as a static 3D array of Enemies like this:

```
Enemy[mountain][2][5] = new Enemy("troll")
```

Where the fields are (from left to right) Location, difficulty, index.

Each location the player enters will populate an ArrayList of Enemies from this static array.

Is there a more efficient data structure to use in this scenario?

(This list will be hard-coded and should not be altered during the course of the program)

edit-

I was hoping to optimize the access time. This game will generate a number of locations, each one needing to randomly draw Enemies from the list based on their origin and difficulty.

As per request, I will put some more thought into the use case of this program. Once I have a proper solution I will update. (Thanks)

Comment: It's unclear, not-object oriented, probably very bug prone. I wouldn't recommend imagining too many array oriented solutions here.

Comment: You need to tell us what kind of efficiency you are trying to optimize

Comment: I was hoping to optimize the access time. This game will generate a number of locations, each one needing to randomly draw Enemies from the list based on their origin and difficulty.

Comment: @Czurch Please add clarifications as edits to your Question rather than post as comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is conceptually wise not a good idea.

You really do not worry about performance at this point. You worry about creating a useful, helpful **object model** that allows you to write elegant, easy-to-read and easy-to-enhance code.

Using a 3D-array achieves *none* of these goals.

In other words: you step back; and think hard about the "use cases" that need to access your Enemy objects. And coming from there, you decide if you should go with different Maps for example; or different Sets, ... instead of using a 3D as central "storage point".

Edit, given your comment: there are two sides here:

1. Arrays are very inflexible in Java. You can't change their size dynamically. And beyond that, they are really "ugly" to use: this going through "3 dimensions" might be convenient for a certain "ascess path"; but it could make *other* things very hard (like when searching for a certain enemy, then you have to do this 3-dim iteration stuff ... as said: ugly)
2. One should try to make designs that are "open" for changes that have a high rate of "taking place". Example: you have a fixed number of enemies today; but assuming your "game" works out for you; you will sooner or later (rather sooner) want to enhance it; for example by allowing dynamic add/removal of enemies. Then a lot of the code you wrote using the 3-D array ... would become a real obstacle.

Beyond that: yes, in a "game world", there should be **one** component that is responsible for keeping track of all elements in the game. But: how this component internally organizes things is more of an implementation detail. You should focus on putting "helpful" methods on that GameWorld first; or as I put it before: understand the ways how your code will need to access/iterate/search enemies to perform the game itself. And then you look into data structures that support these "use cases".

Finally: assuming that this is a learning exercise - you can still start with a 3d array. It will teach you a lot; I am merely pointing out: you would not do that in a more "real world" application; and if you go for this option, you will soon be confronted with certain limitations/obstacles; just by the nature of your solution.

Comment: Pardon for my lack of understanding here. It is not a good idea to store my Enemies in one place? I've tried to think about the different types of ways to store these enemies. But how will I know if I've found the right one?

Answer (score 0):

What comes to mind for me is a map. The location is the key and the value would be a List of objects that represents the enemy and its location - let's call it an EnemyLocation object that contains an Enemy and its location (or you could change Enemy to contain its location which seems like a good idea, but I don't know your code). So, when a player enters the "mountain" region, you do something like enemies.get("mountain") and you get back a List of Enemy objects (or EnemyLocation objects)